# Arrested in Georgia for a DUI with an out of state drivers license

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, driving, georgia, alcohol

It is my understanding that if you are arrested for a DUI in Georgia and you have a Georgia driver's license you have to attend a ALS hearing or having your driver's license suspended. Am I  right about that?

If a person, with a valid driver's license issued from another state, is  arrested in Georgia for a DUI, does he have to attend an ALS hearing so he can drive between the date of the arrest and the trial date?